# How to call a service call in each 2 minutes in angular4 observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, rxjs5, angular4-httpclient

In service

```js
this._ProductUrl =".../api/products"

getProduct(): Observable <IProduct[]>{   
  return this._http.get(this._ProductUrl)
    .map((response:Response) =>  <IProduct[]> response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

app.component.ts

with interval not working

```js
Observable
  .interval(2*60*1000)
  .timeInterval()
  .flatMap((this._productService.getProduct())
  .subscribe((response) => {

}),(err)=> {this.errorMsg =<any>err};
```

while hover over the line some error displays.
Error in this line:

```
    Argument of type '(err: TimeInterval<number>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: TimeInterval<number>, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.

  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'
```

when tried like this

```js
  Observable
    .interval(2*60*1000)
    .timeInterval()
    .flatMap((this._productService.getProduct(response))).subscribe((response) => {

    }),(err)=> {this.errorMsg =<any>err};
```

Error on this line:

```
.flatMap((this._productService.getProduct(response)

 [ts] Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
(property) AppComponent._productService: ProductServic
```

e

**without Interval working fine**

```
 this._productService.getProduct().subscribe((response) => {
console.log(error);

}),(err)=> {this.errorMsg =<any>err};
```

There is some syntax issue with above codes, please provide better solution be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

try like this :

```
Observable.interval(2000).subscribe((x) => {
    this._productService.getProduct()
        .subscribe((response) => {
            console.log('response', response)
        })
})
```

OR using `flatMap()` you can try like this below

```
Observable.interval(2000)
    .timeInterval()
    .flatMap((x) => {
        return this._productService.getProduct()
    })
    .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log('response', response);
    })
```

Comment: `subscribing` within a `subscribe` is a rx anti-pattern. Use `.mergeMap()` to link the inner and outer observable to eachother.

Comment: @MarkvanStraten i have updated answer using `flatMap()` it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with a bit changed error handling and single subscribe:

```
      Observable
        .interval(2000)
        .switchMap(() => {
            return this._productService.getProduct();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // handle errors
            this.errorMsg = <any>err;
            // rethrow error
            return Observable.throw(err);
            // or just return some correct value
            // return Observable.of(new Product())

        })
        .subscribe(response => console.dir(response));
```

UPD: mistake at response logging